# Are all purusarths equally important?

Tags: mahabharata, purushartha

There are four purusarths of life - Dharma, Artha , Kaam and Moksha.

Are all of them equally important ?

Dharma is the path.

Moksha is the end goal.

Artha and Kaam are also goals.

Is there any such thing written anywhere esp. in Mahabharat (as Mbh is the ultimate book to know about these 4 Purusarths) and that has been spoken by any God.

Comment: Why do they have to be evaluated against one and another? Dharma is only a path, if its based on individual choice. However Dharam is the innate nature of all Phenomenon. So a path chosen that is inline with this innate nature of creation will automatically lead to a meaningful outcome which is Artha. Kaama is desire, which is again innate to sentient beings, however people misunderstand the diff between Kaama and Raaga. So a meaningful outcome (Artha) will satisfy the innate Kaama together it leads to Moksha = Moha + Ksheya (depletion of Moha).